# WIndows Phone 8 website just shows a blank/white page

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have set up a mobile version of a full website, and on every device besides Windows Phone 7.5/8 it works fine.

But on Windows Phone 7.5/8 (I dont have a 7.0 phone anymore, so I dont know if that version of IE has that problem) it redirects to the correct page, but it just show a blank/white page.
I have tried removing javascripts and moving stuff around, but I cant really find a spesific thing that makes this error.

Comment: Any chance you can share the URL to the site?

Answer (score 0):

If you use JQuery Mobile, that may be an issue.  This can happen if the JQuery library is being pulled from a site such as Google via HTTP instead of HTTPS when the rest of the site is HTTPS.  Remember the whole 'mixed content' thing in IE?.

If you pull content such as style sheets, images, and/or scripts from both HTTPS and HTTP, that may be an issue.  Also... cert errors on any src= request (again, CSS, scripts, etc) can simply be ignored by mobile IE.

Comment: There are no script running from an external site, the only https link there was I removed and still nothing on the phone.